# Use ember mock server for ember test --server

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, mocking, ember-cli

when running `ember server`, the mocks in `server/mocks` are served properly, such that they can be used in the tests as well (as the tests are in localhost:4200/tests by default and the api from the mock server is available at localhost:4200/).

However when running `ember test --server` the mocks are not available which makes tests that rely on those mocks fail. Is this a bug? How to make the mocks available in the test server?

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing that issue myself and from what I could gather, at the moment you can't. There's a [Pull Request on GitHUB](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/pull/2969) where people talk about implementing that but it seems the direction is to change towards using the [ember-cli-mirage addon](https://github.com/samselikoff/ember-cli-mirage) (currently in version 0.0.24).

I haven't tried the ember-cli-mirage addon, but I did find an [example on how to use it](https://gist.github.com/stefanpenner/1a3b3467059fc9b2f7be#file-asdf-test-js-L40-L72)

```
test('searching', () => {
server.get('/jobs', json(200, {
jobs: [
  job({ title: 'UI Engineer'     }),
  job({ location: 'Palo Alto', title: 'UI Engineer'     }),
  job({ location: 'Palo Alto', title: 'Backend Engineer'}),
]
}));

server.get('/companies', json(200, {
companies: []
}));

return visit('/').then(() => {
equal(numberOfJobs(), 3, 'expected 3 jobs');

fillIn($('#search-field'), 'UI').then(() => {
  equal(numberOfJobs(), 2, 'expected 2 jobs');
});

fillIn($('#search-field'), 'ASDFASDF').then(() => {
  equal(numberOfJobs(), 0, 'expected 0 jobs');
});

fillIn($('#search-field'), 'Palo alto').then(() => {
  equal(numberOfJobs(), 2, 'expected 2 jobs');
});

return fillIn($('#search-field'), '').then(() => {
  equal(numberOfJobs(), 3, 'expected 3 jobs');
});
});
});
```

I hope that this may be of help.